# Creating a Tooltip rectangle and checking when the rectangle leaves the screen

Tags: c#, monogame

I am creating a Tooltip class. Generally, a rectangle will be drawn on top of the mouse position. If the rectangle hits the top side, or the right side, the rectangle would be drawn on the opposite side. This is my code for that:

```
private int LeavesScreen(Rectangle rectangle)
        {
            const int None = 0;
            const int Top = 1;
            const int Right = 2;

            if (rectangle.Y < Viewport.Y)
                return Top;

            else if (rectangle.Right > Viewport.Right)
                return Right;

            return None;
        }
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    switch (LeavesScreen(Rect))
        {
            case 1: //Hits the top side of the screen
                Destination = new Vector2(Rect.X, Rect.Y + Rect.Height);
                Direction = Destination - new Vector2(Rect.X, Rect.Y);
                Direction.Normalize();
                break;
            case 2: //Hits the right side of the screen
                Destination = new Vector2(Rect.X - Rect.Width, Rect.Y);
                Direction = Destination - new Vector2(Rect.X, Rect.Y);
                Direction.Normalize();
                break;
            case 0:
                Direction = Vector2.Zero;
                break;
        }
        Position += Direction;
        Rect = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y - Size.Width, Size.Width, Size.Height);
}
```

Doing this causes the rectangle to jump up and down, I guess this is because when the rectangle hits the edge, it gets moved, after being moved it detects that it does not hit the edge and then returns to the previous position, where it all repeats again.

NOTE: 
I write this: `(int)Position.Y - Size.Width` so that the tooltip appears on top of the mouse, not below it.

I tried adding this inside `case:0`, this works, however, on the upper right half of the screen:

```
if (Viewport.Right - Rect.Right > Rect.Width + Viewport.Width * 0.02f)
                    Direction = Vector2.Zero;
if (Viewport.Top - Rect.Top < -Rect.Height - Viewport.Height * 0.02f)
                    Direction = Vector2.Zero;
```

EDIT: What's the difference if i try on the upper right or lower right side of the screen? Upper side works, lower side does not.
Note2: `0.02f` is used so there is an empty space before it starts detecting collision again

Comment: You could use an offset variable?

Comment: Why do you want the tooltip to appear on the opposite side of the screen or have I misinterpreted?

Comment: @MickyDuncan opposite side of the mouse. Since it draws top right side of the mouse. when it hits the right side it should instead draw on the left side of the mouse. However, I fixed the issue by not letting the tooltip leave the screen, instead of trying to reposition it.

Comment: @Val I understand.  If you fixed the issue you can post an answer to your own question below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by taking a different approach. Instead of trying to reposition the rectangle to the opposite side of the mouse, I totally stop the rectangle from leaving the screen.

When trying to set the `Vector2 Position` of the tooltip, it checks if it leaves the borders.
Like this:

```
public void SetPosition(Vector2 newPosition)
{
    //We remove Size.Height to make the tooltip appear above the mouse, not on top of it
    newPosition = new Vector2(newPosition.X, newPosition.Y - Size.Height);
    string LeavesBoundary = LeavesScreen(new Rectangle((int)newPosition.X, (int)newPosition.Y, (int)this.Size.Width, (int)this.Size.Height));
    if (LeavesBoundary == "top")
    {
        this.Position = new Vector2(newPosition.X, Viewport.Top);
    }
    else if (LeavesBoundary == "right")
    {
        this.Position = new Vector2(Viewport.Right - this.Size.Width, newPosition.Y);
    }
    else if (LeavesBoundary == "topRight")
    {
        this.Position = new Vector2(Viewport.Right - this.Size.Width, Viewport.Top);
    }
    else
        this.Position = newPosition;
}
```

And here is the updated `LeavesScreen` method:

```
private string LeavesScreen(Rectangle rectangle)
{
    if (rectangle.Top < Viewport.Top)
    {
        //If the rectangle leaves the top part, create a new rectangle and see if it leaves the right part too. If it does, return "topRight"
        Rectangle x = new Rectangle(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        if (x.Right > Viewport.Right)
            return "topRight";
        return "top";
    }

    if (rectangle.Right > Viewport.Right)
    {
        //Same as above, if it leaves right side, check if it leaves top side too.
        Rectangle x = new Rectangle(rectangle.X - rectangle.Width, rectangle.Y, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        if (x.Y < Viewport.Y)
            return "topRight";
        return "right";
    }
    return "none";
}
```